# Make text present in PDF document, but invisible

Tags: css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

How can I have text in an HTML document so that it will be “there” in the PDF document (generated via `wkhtmltopdf`), but invisible when viewed or printed?

Constraints:

- The text must appear at the right place, with the right size, because the purpose is to find the text with an automated tool and discover its co-ordinates and size on the page.
- The solution must be to do with the text only, because I'm trying to keep this simply about CSS styles. Any “hide it under another element” doesn't address the problem, because there might not be any other element at those co-ordinates.
- The solution can't be dependent on what's already on the page; I can't go inspecting the background elements on the page because I can't determine those dynamically. The text should be invisible in its own right.
- The text must be findable with an automated tool (e.g. `pdfgrep`), which means `wkhtmltopdf` must place the text in the document file.

  So a “display: none” style or “opacity: 0” doesn't work, because that makes the text not exist at all in the PDF document.

So I want to have an HTML document, place a text element “FOO” within that document with an inline CSS style, and process it through `wkhtmltopdf`; then, `pdfgrep FOO` should find the text, the text location and size should be correct, but the text should not show up in HTML, not appear when the PDF is viewed, and not appear when it's printed.

Comment: Do you need this to work in an automated way to produce *many* documents like that? Or would it be good enough if you can achieve your goal by semi-manually editing the PDF after its creation?

Comment: Uhmmm.... just realizing: you do not state clearly if the text should be visible in HTML, but not in the PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a style of [`color: transparent;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#transparent_keyword) the text will be fully transparent on the page, but show up normally for any tool looking in the document for that text.

Answer (score 1):

## I.

The PDF syntax supports different *"text rendering modes"*. These lets a PDF creating software (or anybody who authors a PDF with a simple text editor) render any text, regardless the chosen font, as

- outlined only,
- filled only,
- outlined and filled,
- neither filled nor outlined (invisible),
- plus some more, which deal with clipping.

Here is the illustration from the PDF specification:

[image: Text rendering modes in PDF specification]

However, this is not supported by HTML or CSS (at least AFAIK). So your only option to get it done in a similar way is to...

- ...either set the background color in HTML to the same as the text color,
- ...or set the text color to transparent.

Then hope that `htmltopdf` will translate that into a PDF which represents the same...

## II.

The following HTML code (essentially using *`style="color:transparent"`*) works for me. You'll have to decide whether it fullfills your requirements completely:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="color:transparent; background:red; border: 1px dashed currentColor;">
          The color of this text is transparent/invisible. <br />
          The background of this text is red.

          <div style="background:blue; height:9px;"></div>

          Above this text is a blue box with a height of 9px. <br />
          This block is surrounded by a transparent border.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, when opening the PDF I cannot read any text lines, but I can select/mark/highlight them.

When running

```
 pdftotext -layout my.html -
```

I see the following text:

```
The color of this text is transparent/invisible.
The background of this text is red.
Above this text is a blue box with a height of 9px.
This block is surrounded by a transparent border.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make text colored with background color of your PDF (ex. white).

Comment: Already addressed in the question: The program inserting this element doesn't know what the colour of the background this text will end up on.

Comment: Another solution: "opacity: 0;"